Kid with illness befriends school bully
There's this movie about a blond kid with glasses and crutches who moves next door to the school bully. They become friends and the bully starts even carrying him on his shoulders, they write a book together with something about "monster" on the title (reference to the ill boy)...
When the bully starts worrying about his friend's life, he tells him there is a place in town where they're gonna manufacture a new body for him and everything is going to be fine.
Of course the boy dies in the end and the bully runs crying and upset to said place, only to discover it's just a textile factory
This is the 1st movie that made me cry actually

The Mighty

This tells the story of a strong friendship between a young boy with
  Morquio's syndrome and an older boy who is always bullied because of
  his size.


In the poster you can see the big lad carrying the crippled lad on his shoulders.
Wikipedia:

The two escape into a nearby lake with Kevin riding on Max's shoulders
  and they make it out okay.
Recalling his conversation with Kevin on how he would get a new body
  from a research center, Max heads there immediately, only to discover
  that Kevin had lied and the research center is really a commercial
  laundromat. Max breaks down among the workers.
Inspired by their bond, Max remembers Kevin and all the adventures
  they had and he decides to write it all in the empty book Kevin had
  given him. Max eventually gets writer's block on the last page so he
  puts an illustration of King Arthur's grave, which reads, "Here Lies
  King Arthur, Once and Future King", to symbolize his belief that he
  will see Kevin again.

